# Adding more features dont help

Tags: discussion

Frequently users ask a question regarding a feature they need, but can not find. Why do we not as a whole recognize that:

1. Adding more feature is a tradeof between, ease of use. A software on the whole does not become better with more features. But in fact a software should have less more generally usable features (this is hard to do).

   This is reinforced by the sheer volume of questions assuming the feature they seek does not exist, but infact does.
2. A feature misimplemented can be less than useful, and degrade all users experience.

   The best example of this that you would generally know is Illustrators perspective grid tool. It is an amazing feat in fact, i can see how it perfectly manages to tick all the customer request points and yet be totally useless. Worse it sits on the toolbox and unlike all other tools in the toolbox manages to permanently alter your settings when you click it. Causing any misclick to move you into a different mode that can not be turned of from toolbar, confusing new users to no end. That on the whole tge tool still manages to be worse than drawing perspectives manually.
3. Inorder for you to have a good tool you need to think how the feature affects the whole. This is hard, in fact if you have never released software you can not understand how even the simplest of features can confuse large fractions of your userbase.

Comment: I agree with all of this (the perspective tool is such a good example - I hate the way it's implemented), but I fail to understand what kind of answers you expect here. Are we talking about features on Stack Exchange or features in for example Adobe software? Are you looking for a standardized way to handle users who gets angry at the software instead of accepting the way it is?

Comment: @Wolff Its not a question its an explanation this is discussion

Comment: I understand that, I was just unsure if you were talking specifically about features on this site. I thought meta was for discussions about this site. But I see now that you probably mean features in software in general.

Comment: @Wolff its a discussion for people on the site to move off the commentt sections

Comment: The traditional way for such discussions would be a chat, if I'm not mistaken? I was also quite unsure what features - site vs. applications - you were referring to.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher lol, if we can have a ask questions session in meta we can have anything in meta. But in both sites and applications

Comment: @joojaa I honestly don't know how to parse your last comment - what is the goal of this question and what kind of discussion are you aiming for?

Answer (score 2):

Making these assumptions based on questions on a Q&A site adds some confirmation bias, of course - the people who had no issue with finding what they are looking for or using it are less likely to show up here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe much of what Adobe actually implements in AI all comes down to *cost*.

Surely there are users, or even developers, that see the pain points and make them known. But ultimately I think what is or is not developed, refined, and/or implemented is all reduced to cost vs sales equation somewhere. The **accounting** department dictates just how much dev time can be assigned. Then it's up to team leaders to sort out what can and can't be done for that cost.

Adobe adds stupid stuff at times all in a quest for more $$$.

- Example, the **Bounding Box**. It was aded *specifically* to make CorelDraw users more comfortable in Illustrator. And it has absolutely **no** unique feature within Illustrator. It's an application feature that is *nothing* more than overhead.

Sometimes it seems overhead to the application is added to combat anyone actually having to *learn* a feature set as opposed to merely throwing everything directly in front of a user.

- Example, the **Free Transform Tool** and it's pop up tool bar. **None** of those "tools" are "new". All those transformations have been possible with the Free Transform tool since the 1980s. But many users, not having actually explored the Free Transform Tool features, were unaware that those transformations could be performed. So, Adobe added overhead in the form of a pop up tool bar needlessly to placate the ignorant sector. And then they sell it as a "new feature".

And then there are times where I believe the dev teams *know* they need to improve things, but due to cost limitations they are not allowed to. New bells and whistles tend to garner more new customers (subscribers) far, far, more than improvements to existing, sometimes little used, features.

- Example, **Live Color**. Such a *powerful* feature but has so many limitations in how it's implemented that you can easily hit a "wall" and have to step back, start over, and rethink a direction. I believe Devs *know* all this. They simply aren't *allowed* to devote time to correct it.

---

All of this, I feel, leads to an application that *quickly* become "bloatware" and actually *less* usable.

I, personally, have *never* liked *any* "CC" version of Illustrator. They *all* see far to "muddled" while working. I can't specifically state any direct mechanics that are problematic for me. It's all more of a "feel" to the application.

I much prefer CS6 to this day. Even though CC does have some feature sets that I can see as useful to production. CS6 "feels" snappy, responsive, and "awake" - for lack of a better term. CC versions "feel" like they are in a daze, everything feels like it's more concerned with being "smooth" in it's mouse movements than it is in being *accurate*. I feel as though I'm working in 2 feet of water when I use any CC version. None the less I do use CC at times for a couple features unavailable in CS6. However, since CS6 I have not been in a hurry or felt compelled to move my work to CC. There's little need 99.9% of the time for me.

<sub>And, admittedly, the entire "subscription" model where I'm locked out of any of my *copyrighted* work if it's saved in a CC format unless I pay Adobe **really** irks me. I can't have my artwork being help hostage as a "business model".</sub>

---

Unfortunately, due to the age of CS6 and how fast turnaround is in the industry, many users *only* know CC versions and that's all they'll *ever* know. And you simply can't know how much better something can be if you've only ever been exposed to one flavor. It is never surprising to me if younger designers merely assume "that's how things are". They've been told to accept what they are given... and they don't know how much better something *could* be.

Comment: +1, I couldn't agree more. I'm dreaming of graphical applications which are developed with a constant desire to minimize everything until you are left with the smallest number of tools necessary. I don't need a tomato dicer, a parsley chopper, an egg divider and a bread cutter. I just want a good sharp knife and a cutting board! But as you said: it's a consequence of capitalism and maybe also democracy - everybody has the right to be a designer/author/musician/chef/whatever.